# Issues with calling child method in parent's class in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual

I have a base class an a child class.  Inside the base class there is a virtual function called `constructionDebugInfo()`, and it's called at the end of the base's constructor.

I'm trying to print out different debug messages for when the base class is instantiated, or the child class is.  Each time though, I only get the base class's `constructionDebugInfo()` message.  Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: _" Is there a reason why this is happening?"_ Probably because the function is not `virtual`.

Comment: `constructionDebugIfno()` is virtual in the base class.

Comment: It's happening because you haven't posted an SSCCE.

Comment: ^http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Isn't one of Meyer's tips in Effective C++ "Don't call virtual functions in constructors or destructors"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During execution of the base class constructor, the object does not know that it will eventually become an object of a derived class. That's why the function in the base class is called instead of the one in the derived class.

Comment: So is it impossible to achieve this?

Comment: Correct. You wil have to find some other way to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Benjamin _"So is it impossible to achieve this?"_ Not really impossible. If the base class knows about the child class (e.g. given as template parameter), it's possible using a `static_cast<Child*>(this)->constructionDebugInfo();`, but you'll need to be careful not to access any uninitialized stuff from the child class.